# Can't create CNAME Record in domains for openshift app

Tags: dns, openshift, point, recording

I have a domain `(mydomain.ir)`. I use  `nirc.ir`  Route  to point this comain to a server hosted on EC2 (openshift servers). I am unable able to add a CNAME record for `'www.mydomain.com'` or `'someprefix.mydomain.com'`, becuase  nirc.ir  has  only NS record for `'mydomain.com'` and does not allow to add a CNAME record for 'mydomain.com'.also openshift dont provide static ip for my app, so it would be risky if i use only my app ip!.

I need this record to be able to type the domain with or without the leading **'www'** in the browser.

More important, I plan to run a mail server on the machine and I believe mail clients need to resolve the `'mydomain.com'` part of my user email addresses (e.g. user@mydomain.com).

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Someone may provide a better answer but I would suggest that you switch domain providers to someone who supports CNAME entries.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found the Answer, i used **cloudflare.com** as a **CDN** and there i could set **CNAME** and others and finally it give me a **NS record** which i set it in my main domain provider and it works.

Thanks a lot for your attention